# Issue with writing into ProgramData with SYSTEM account during installation

Tags: permissions, windows-installer, exe, programdata, local-system-account

I am trying to install an application (using the SYSTEM account) that installs some certificates in the ProgramData folder by creating a new folder inside it. The installation fails at the stage where it tries to install these certificates.

During the certificate installation process, all it does is create a folder inside ProgramData and write files into it.

I have given FULL CONTROL permission to the SYSTEM user on the ProgramData folder and passed it to subfolders as well.

I have tried executing the .exe file using PSexec tool (this enables using the SYSTEM account). I had opened the PSexec tool from a command prompt that I started using Run as Administrator.

I have also tried extracting the .msi file and run it using TaskScheduler with Elevated Privileges.

I have also manually created the Folders that should be created during installation(in case they do not exist) and given FULL CONTROL permission to the SYSTEM user. I created the Folders using Administrator account and using SYSTEM account. Installation still did not succeed.

The application is a 32-bit application. So, I tried installing it in a 32-bit Windows. It still failed.

I believe the root cause is that permissions to create folders/files in the ProgramData Folder are not there for the SYSTEM account.

Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: When you say "using the system account" do you mean from (say) a service or task scheduler process? Or maybe from a custom action running with the system account? Does "install" certificate just mean you're copying the files there just like any other file? Or do you mean registering them in the certificate store?  When it fails, could you show the full error, and you could look in a verbose installer log too.

Comment: File permissions are unlikely to be the problem.  Try Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to see what the installer is trying to do.